# How to return an object and the result of an operation in a C# method

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I'm developing an C# library with .NET Framework 4.0.

I have a method that has to return an object and the result of that operation. In my case it is a login method, I use as argument user name and password, and I have to return an instance of User class and the result of the login operation:

- Invalid user name or password.
- User locked.
- User disabled.
- Etc.

I thought, I can do it this way:

```
public LoginResult DoLogin(string userName, string password, out User user)
```

Is that correct? Is there another way to do it? Maybe I can use an exception instead of return a `LoginResult` value.

Comment: If it is an exceptional condition that the login will fail, then throw an exception. If the method is intended for testing whether a login will succeed, then it should return an error code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is an appropriate way if there is no further information assigned with the states such as *user locked* or *user disabled*.

If there is, I'd like to suggest an alternative model:

Create an abstract class `LoginResultInfo` that has an abstract read-only property of type `LoginResult` that will return the "error code".

From that class, you can then derive a subclass for each of the desired error codes. Each of these subclasses overrides the `LoginResult` property to return the appropriate error code, and each contains the relevant additional fields, such as a `User` instance in the case of a successful login, a text originally supplied by an admin explaining why a user was locked, or the timestamp of when a user disabled their account etc.

With the `LoginResult` property, you still have a way to conveniently switch over the different error codes, while at the same time, you don't supply any fields that are used only sometimes, but instead you have a class structure specific and suitable to the situation at hand.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an appropriate way, as some framework functionls like [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) do it exactly this way.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to make `LoginResult` a property of `User` class and return the `User` class object from your `DoLogin` method instead of returning it as on output parameter.
You can always fill the `LoginResult` property while filling your `User` object as the purpose of having a `User` class means the user `instance` is either `authenticated` or `unauthenticated` by the value of `LoginResult`

```
public User DoLogin(string userName, string password){}

public class User
{
    public LoginResult UserLoginResult {get; set;} 

    // Other properties.....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method you suggested is the most appropriate one according to your requirement.
One more point I will like to highlight,

1. It is not a good practice to decide the flow of the program by throwing exceptions.

The other ideas that pops up in my mind are,

1. Generate a class having both the properties and return that object
2. Return a `KeyValuePair<LoginResult, User >`  object

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Tuple<User, LoginResult>
```